# How to trigger dialogDidCancel message from FBPermissionDialog?

Tags: api, facebook, authentication

FBPermissionDialog is official Facebook iPhone lib.
But my code to triggering message

```
- (void)dialogDidCancel:(FBDialog*)dialog
```

is not working.
What can I do for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was wrong place.
The triggering method should be

```
/**
 * Called when a user closes the login dialog without logging in.
 */
- (void)sessionDidNotLogin:(FBSession*)session;
```

I hope this help.